# Storing experiment data in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql

I create a database to store the results of the experiment (data1 data2 data3 time ) and display these data on a chart. In addition, I also need to display the id of the experiment and add the ability to select an experiment by this id in order to display the data of a particular experiment, and for this I added the idexp column (in this case, the id is 0, since the experiment is the first). Can I do that, or is this a bad implementation? And I'm still confused about storing data for the next experiments, can I just store them below under the data of the first experiment in the same table, or do I need to create other tables and link them? And in general, for some reason I'm not sure what I made). The data is written abstractly.

[image]

Comment: *"Can I do that, or is this a bad implementation?"* - not really. *"And I'm still confused about storing data for the next experiments"* - can't you use `idexp` "1" for the next experiment? then use subsequent numbers for the next experiments.

Comment: *"for some reason I'm not sure what I made. The data is written abstractly."* - you should for one, be sure how your data want to be handled. though, word of advice, you should be able to differentiate between rows of the same experiment - use a surrogate key or something.

Comment: Ah, I likely incorrectly stated thought, I represent as the data will be processed. In this case, 10 lines are the data of the first experiment. And after them, 10 more lines would go, only with idexp 1, but they told me that this was a strange decision and asked to normalize the database, but I don’t see any solution

Comment: err, i'm not sure the normalization they wanted. could you clarify with them? i mean, its normalized enough - unless they wanted to have `data1`, `data2`, `data3`, ..., `dataN`. fyi, normalizing stuff too much and you might end up writing a very complicated query and sacrifices speed. thats why, *how your data will be used* is **very** important.

Comment: I agree with you, I'd better clarify all the details. Thank you very much for your time)